# Отображение вложенных списков

Tags: javascript

В [анимированном списке с фильтром](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/animated-list-filtering-searching-search-filter/) вложенные подсписки 3го уровня накладываются поверх следующего второго (файл используется на мобильном устройстве):[image: screen]

Что не так с разметкой?

```
<style>
body { margin: 0; font: .9em lucida grande, helvetica, sans-serif }
header { padding: 1em 1.4em; background: #f3f3f3; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd }
input { padding: .4em }
li { list-style: none; padding: 1.2em 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea; color:rgba(0,0,0,.6); text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,.2) 2px 6px 5px,rgba(255,255,255,.4) 0 -4px 30px; }
</style>

<header>
<input placeholder=Search autofocus class=search><!-- search.js input -->
</header>

<ul class=search>
<li>JavaScript</li>
<li>Java</li>
<li>jQuery</li>
<li>AngularJS</li>
<li>ReactJS</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Submunu 1</li>
            <ul>
                <li>Submenu 1.2</li>
            </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Submenu 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Submenu 3</li>
    </ul>
<li>Bootstrap</li>
<li>PHP</li>
<li>Python</li>
</ul>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  "use strict"

  var style = ""
    + "<style>"
    +   "input.search {"
    +     "-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;"
    +   "}"
    +   ".search .hidden {"
    +     "opacity: 0;"
    +     "pointer-events: none;"
    +   "}"
    +   ".search > * {"
    +     "position: absolute;"
    +     "transition: .5s;"
    +   "}"
    + "</style>"

  document.head.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", style)

  var items = document.querySelectorAll(".search > *")
  var itemHeight = items[0].offsetHeight
  var texts = []
  var i = -1
  var len = items.length
  var transform = "transform" in document.body.style ? "transform" : "webkitTransform"

  while (++i < len) {
    texts.push(items[i].textContent.trim())
    items[i].style[transform] = "translateY(" + i*itemHeight +"px)"
  }

  document.querySelector("input.search").addEventListener("input", function() {
    var re = new RegExp(this.value, "i")
    texts.forEach(function(element, index) {
      if (re.test(element)) {
        items[index].classList.remove("hidden")
      }
      else {
        items[index].classList.add("hidden")
      }
      var i = -1
      var position = 0
      while (++i < len) {
        if (items[i].className != "hidden") {
          items[i].style[transform] = "translateY(" + position++ * itemHeight + "px)"
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
</script>
```

И сразу второй вопрос. Как сделать вложенные списки изначально скрытыми и раскрытие происходило по клику родителя? Спасибо.

Comment: С разметкой у вас все в порядке. Проблема в стилях для этого списка. Погуглите на подобие "выпадающее меню на css". Ответ и на второй вопрос сразу сам придет. Их просто нужно сделать изначально скрытыми `display: none`

Comment: @Сергей с чего ты взял что все в порядке? А как же закрытый тег `li` у `Submunu 1` в котором есть под список?

Comment: @core Поправь разметку, как я написал в комментарии выше

Comment: Убрал закрытый тег, но на отображение никак не повлияло. Методом тыка выяснил, что конфликт идет из стиля position: absolute; в js, а как исправить незнаю. Без этого атрибута элементы списка "расползаются".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправь разметку:

```
<ul>
    <li>Submunu 1</li> <!-- закрытый тег -->
        <ul>
           <li>Submenu 1.2</li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

На:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Submunu 1
        <ul>
           <li>Submenu 1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li> <!-- должен быть здесь -->
</ul>
```

Сделал пример такой же как у тебя, только без JS. Используя библиотеку `animate.css`. Можешь взять [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css) определенные стили анимации, которые нужны именно тебе, и использовать, если не хочешь грузить всю библиотеку. Непонятно зачем ты используешь JS...

Готовый пример: http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/reoYGb

Comment: [Теперь вот так](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ItDQB.png)

Comment: @core теперь правильно, просто теперь задайте стили для меню и под меню, и все будет хорошо. А `position: absolute;` лучше не использовать, да и не понятно зачем. https://jsfiddle.net/x1s3e4p6/ у меня все в порядке

Comment: @core обновил ответ

Comment: Василий, на мобильном устройстве, если не переносить тег </li> и отключить файл скрипта, то получается что  третий уровень списка отображается даже [правильнее](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cZIZg.png). Но как только подключаешь скрипт - оба варианта искажаются. Если из скрипта убрать position, список еще и разъезжается вниз. Может это особенность мобильных браузеров..

Comment: @core ты видел как я изменил ответ? что добавил в него? что убрал? Все должно работать. Твой скрипт я просто удалил, т.к. не понятно зачем он вообще нужен

Comment: Пишу со смарта, не смотрел пока, интернет слабый. Скрипт фильтрации у меня вынесен в отдельный файл просто. Если записать его в тело - тоже самое. На счет того, зачем нужен? Именно что фильтрационный список и нужен. Для личных целей.

Comment: @core фильтрация тут не причем, как будет возможность посмотри код который я привел в `готовый пример`.